# Android - navigation among fragments from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am making an app that has the navigation drawer. Within those fragments it is possible to go to other activities. If I click on the back button, I would like to return to the current fragment of the navigation drawer. For example I have a fragment Message then I click within the fragment on the specified chat so I will see the detail. Then I would like to get back to the message fragment again. I was thinking about using fragment backstack but I am not sure if the right way to do it. Here is my code how I am creating fragments within the navigation drawer.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_inbox:
            fragmentClass = ChatFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_map:
            fragmentClass = MapFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_dog_breed:
            fragmentClass = DogBreedsFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_reminder:
            fragmentClass = ReminderFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_favourite_dog_breeds:
            fragmentClass = FavouriteDogBreedsFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_help:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            ((FirebaseApplication) getApplication()).signOutUser(this);
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;

    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain the fragment");

    }

    if (fragment != null && fragmentClass != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
    }
```

For example in ChatDetailActivity I need to get to ChatFragment

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // here I would need to return to the current fragment
}
```

Thanks for any advices

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 0):

Fragment backstack is the way to go. Add your fragment replace transaction to the backstack, so when you press the back button, you will return to the fragment you were on.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

If you want to return to the same fragment after launching an activity from the navigation drawer, you will need to save the name (and possibly state) of the current fragment before launching the activity. When the navigation drawer activity is restored, check for any saved state and restore it.

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to save the name of the fragment within the main activity where is the navigation drawer. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @user3637775 You can use `onSaveInstanceState()`